# Reading QRCode with Zxing in Java

Tags: java, zxing, qr-code, code128

Some questions about using Zxing...

I write the following code to read barcode from an image:

```
public class BarCodeDecode 
{
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            String tmpImgFile = "D:\\FormCode128.TIF";

            Map<DecodeHintType,Object> tmpHintsMap = new EnumMap<DecodeHintType, Object>(DecodeHintType.class);
            tmpHintsMap.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
            tmpHintsMap.put(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, EnumSet.allOf(BarcodeFormat.class));
            tmpHintsMap.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.FALSE);

            File tmpFile = new File(tmpImgFile);
            String tmpRetString = BarCodeUtil.decode(tmpFile, tmpHintsMap);
            //String tmpRetString = BarCodeUtil.decode(tmpFile, null);
            System.out.println(tmpRetString);
        }
        catch (Exception tmpExpt)
        {
            System.out.println("main: " + "Excpt err! (" + tmpExpt.getMessage() + ")");
        }
        System.out.println("main: " + "Program end.");
    }

}

public class BarCodeUtil 
{
    private static BarcodeFormat DEFAULT_BARCODE_FORMAT = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;

    /**
      * Decode method used to read image or barcode itself, and recognize the barcode,
      * get the encoded contents and returns it.
      * @param whatFile image that need to be read.
      * @param config configuration used when reading the barcode.
      * @return decoded results from barcode.
      */
     public static String decode(File whatFile, Map<DecodeHintType, Object> whatHints) throws Exception 
     {
         // check the required parameters
         if (whatFile == null || whatFile.getName().trim().isEmpty())
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("File not found, or invalid file name.");
         BufferedImage tmpBfrImage;
         try 
         {
             tmpBfrImage = ImageIO.read(whatFile);
         } 
         catch (IOException tmpIoe) 
         {
             throw new Exception(tmpIoe.getMessage());
         }
         if (tmpBfrImage == null)
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not decode image.");
         LuminanceSource tmpSource = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(tmpBfrImage);
         BinaryBitmap tmpBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(tmpSource));
         MultiFormatReader tmpBarcodeReader = new MultiFormatReader();
         Result tmpResult;
         String tmpFinalResult;
         try 
         {
             if (whatHints != null && ! whatHints.isEmpty())
                 tmpResult = tmpBarcodeReader.decode(tmpBitmap, whatHints);
             else
                 tmpResult = tmpBarcodeReader.decode(tmpBitmap);
             // setting results.
             tmpFinalResult = String.valueOf(tmpResult.getText());
         } 
         catch (Exception tmpExcpt) 
         {
             throw new Exception("BarCodeUtil.decode Excpt err - " + tmpExcpt.toString() + " - " + tmpExcpt.getMessage());
         }
         return tmpFinalResult;
    }
}
```

I try to read the following two images that contains code128 and QRCode.

[image]
[image]

It can work for the code128 but not for the QRCode.
Any one knows why...

Comment: To solve this problem, I finally cut out the area where the barcode and QRCode locate in my program.  Then they can be recognized.

Comment: how did you cut-out the area / specify it? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: Dear mmcrae, I first read the entire image to buffer ---->  BufferedImage tmpBfrImage = ImageIO.read(whatFile);  then use method getSubimage ---->   BufferedImage tmpBarCodeBfrImage = tmpBfrImage.getSubimage(whatBarCodeArea.x, whatBarCodeArea.y, whatBarCodeArea.width, whatBarCodeArea.height);

Comment: Your code works for me

Answer (score 10):

Please go through this [link](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-qr-code/) for complete Tutorial. The author of this code is Joe. **I have not developed this code**, so I am just doing Copy paste to make sure this is available in case link is broken.

The author is using ZXing(Zebra Crossing Library) you can download it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/), for this tutorial.

**QR Code Write and Read Program in Java:**

```
package com.javapapers.java;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.NotFoundException;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.ErrorCorrectionLevel;

public class QRCode {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws WriterException, IOException,
      NotFoundException {
    String qrCodeData = "Hello World!";
    String filePath = "QRCode.png";
    String charset = "UTF-8"; // or "ISO-8859-1"
    Map<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new HashMap<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();
    hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

    createQRCode(qrCodeData, filePath, charset, hintMap, 200, 200);
    System.out.println("QR Code image created successfully!");

    System.out.println("Data read from QR Code: "
        + readQRCode(filePath, charset, hintMap));

  }

  public static void createQRCode(String qrCodeData, String filePath,
      String charset, Map hintMap, int qrCodeheight, int qrCodewidth)
      throws WriterException, IOException {
    BitMatrix matrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(
        new String(qrCodeData.getBytes(charset), charset),
        BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, qrCodewidth, qrCodeheight, hintMap);
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile(matrix, filePath.substring(filePath
        .lastIndexOf('.') + 1), new File(filePath));
  }

  public static String readQRCode(String filePath, String charset, Map hintMap)
      throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NotFoundException {
    BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
        new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(
            ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(filePath)))));
    Result qrCodeResult = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap,
        hintMap);
    return qrCodeResult.getText();
  }
}
```

**Maven dependency for the ZXing QR Code library:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
  <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I was under the impression that QR Code Readers aren't *designed* to work with UTF-8, but they sometimes are able to guess it correctly. The standard to use is ISO-8859-1 I believe

Answer (score 8):

Curiously your code works for me, but I had to remove the follow hint.

`tmpHintsMap.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.FALSE);`

When my image is not pure barcode, this hint broke my result.

Thank you!

Comment: Correct, you do not want to set this to anything. It is 'true' if it has any value at all. Hmm. Maybe that's not the best thing.

Comment: odd that that would prevent it from finding non-barcodes as that's what it seems intended to do

Answer (score 0):

This Code worked for me.

```
public static List<string> ScanForBarcodes(string path)
{
  return ScanForBarcodes(new Bitmap(path));
}

public static List<string> ScanForBarcodes(Bitmap bitmap)
{
  // initialize a new Barcode reader.
  BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader
  {
    TryHarder = true, // TryHarder is slower but recognizes more Barcodes
    PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> // in the ZXing There is an Enum where all supported barcodeFormats were contained
    {
      BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 
      BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
      //BarcodeFormat. ... ;
    }
  };
  return reader.DecodeMultiple(bitmap).Select(result => result.Text).ToList(); // return only the barcode string.
                                                                               // If you want the full Result use: return reader.DecodeMultiple(bitmap);
}
```

Did you use [this](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/) (ZXing.Net) Lib?

Comment: I am using its java library.

Comment: Is ZXing.net broken? It is not working for me at all. The Decode method always returns null.