# Java QR Reader library

Tags: java, qr-code

I was wondering if there's any library in java (.jar) which let me take the data readed by the QR scanner/reader. I'm using a Voyager 1452g from Honeywell and the only libs i see are created for android/ios/javascript.

Example:

I scan a QR code and I know there's a text like: "this is a sample" and when I scan it, there's a function of the library that allows me to store this text into a String.

Any information will be very usefull, thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863466/reading-qrcode-with-zxing-in-java or https://www.callicoder.com/qr-code-reader-scanner-in-java-using-zxing/ ? Also android libs are in java and so if you get their source code, you can compile the shared libraries to any platform you like.

Comment: Oh and also take a look at this: https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Comment: Oh, i missed zxing, thanks @Maximus and Amongalen i will try it